# Transform (rotate / translate) change the z-index of my text

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate the first letter of my word. But once it's rotated, it comes on top of everything else (z-index), and none of the other elements can come over this letter (but they can go over the rest of the word, that is not rotated).

```css
.rotating-letter {
  float: left;
  transform: translate(0, .18em) rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span className='rotating-letter'>H</span>
  <span>ello</span>
</h1>
```

Left part of the image shows that the pink part comes over the word, but on the right side, you see the H stays on top

[image]

And if I remove the transform, other elements can come back on top of my letter.
I hope it's understandable !
Many thanks !

Comment: [Transform values other than "none"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) create a [new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Managed to fix it ! Many thanks for your help :)